# Why is only of my two variable increment statements working?

Tags: php

This is driving me nuts.  I've spent a couple hours trying to debug this but I'm getting nowhere.  `$total` should increment by `1` everytime `$result != 'REMAKE'` but it's only incrementing whenever `$result == 1` (and not when `$result == 0`).  I cannot figure out why.  I've tried `$total += 1` but it makes no difference.

`didAccountWinMatch()` will return either `0`, `1`, or `'REMAKE'`.

```
$total = 0;
$wins = 0;
if (isset($match)) {
    foreach ($match as $key => $value) {  
        $result = didAccountWinMatch($accountId, $match[$key]);     
        if ($result != "REMAKE") {
            $total ++;
            $wins += $result;
        }           
    } 
} else {
    $total = 0;
    $wins = 0;
}
```

Comment: `$wins` is incrementing?

Comment: Yes.  To be specific, it's value is increased by the value of `$result`.  So it increments by `1` when `$result == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `!==` instead of `!=`. If you use the loose comparison operator between an integer and a string, the string is converted to an integer first. Converting the string `REMAKE` to an integer results in `0`, so the code is equivalent to

```
if ($result != 0)
```

when `$result` is an integer.

The strict comparison operator `!==` doesn't perform type conversion; if the operands are different types it returns `false`.

Comment: Trying this, will report back.  UPDATE:  This works!  Thank you so much!  For the explanation too.